# Convert to memoir class

Tags: memoir, report

I would like to convert the following code from report class to memoir class and display the same result in figure

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% Update \@chapter to insert the chapter ornament in the LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{%
     \protect\addvspace{10\p@}% Default space between chapters in LoF
     \protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}% Add chapter ornament
  }}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lofchapter}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\hfill
  \textsc{Chapter #1}\hfill
  \rule[.5ex]{.4\linewidth}{.2ex}\par
  \nobreak
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Third chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Last chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[21-30]\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[31-40]\begin{figure}\caption{Last figure}\end{figure}
\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because your document consists only of filler text and figures, all you need is to change `report` to `memoir` in the first line. However, is there a particular result you want to achieve with the `memoir` class? If so, you'll want to edit your question so that we're answering the question you actually want us to answer.

Comment: Please see the photo

Comment: I see the photo, and can‘t see, what you seem to see. Please add explanation to your question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy with memoir, just replace the patch with

```
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
  %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
}
```

or even easier as memoir autoloads etoolbox

```
\apptocmd\insertchapterspace{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofchapter{\thechapter}}%
}{}{}
```

Comment: Please I want remove word chapter from LOF  if there are no figure the same for tables .

Comment: @Ouss there is no way for it to know that at the point when the code is added. There was not in your report version either. You will probably have to hook into each caption in order to add it via the first caption in each chapter. I cannot help you there as that is a different question than what you posted here.